# Ignore Dacpac Snapshot options during publish

Tags: dac, sqlpackage, snapshot-isolation, read-committed-snapshot

Is it possible to ignore the snapshot options set in a given database project's project settings, when deploying its dacpac (either through sqlpackage.exe, DacFx or Visual Studio)?

Answer (score 1):

You can ignore all database properties during a dacpac publish... you can't specify which properties to ignore but they can all be ignored using /p:ScriptDatabaseOptions=False with sqlpackage.exe, for example